# Is it possible to make ng-grid responsive?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm using the Angular.js 'ng-grid' data grid and am trying to make its behavior responsive. When I resize the screen I'd prefer the grid columns to become stackable automatically as opposed to keeping the grid a fixed width.

I've found a few links mentioning a defunct `ngGridLayoutPlugin` that all lead to a dead end on GitHub. I've also seen other grids like `angular-deckgrid` but I'm not interested at this point in changing grids.

Is there anyway to make `ng-grid` responsive?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found a solution to this that worked nicely. The native Bootstrap table has a class that can be applied named `table-responsive` (see: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive). The application to a standard Bootstrap table is to wrap it in this class. The responsive nature is one if the screen gets smaller the table itself will get scroll bars but *not* the entire page.

You can wrap a `ng-grid` with this same class and achieve the *identical* behavior:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions">

  </div>
</div>
```

If you test this with and without the `<div>` wrapper containing the `table-responsive` class you can see the difference between the scrollbars wither being just on the table/grid (responsive), or when not using it, the entire page scrolls (not responsive).

Comment: I'm wondering why this works. 'ngGrid' doesn't use tables. This solution seems very sketchy to me.

Comment: You should be able to page inspect the differences with and without to see how it is rendered and which styles are applied to highlight how it works/behaves.

Comment: The question remains: Why are you using `.table-responsive` for a collections of divs (ngGrid)?

Comment: I believe the reason this works upon further investigation is because if you look at Bootstrap's CSS file for `table-responsive`, the main styles are HTML element agnostic, and thus the restyling to make responisve is working on both a `<div>` or obviously a `<table>`. There are more styles to be applied if it is a `<table>`. Would I love it if a `div-responsive` or `ng-grid-responsive` class existed? Sure, but they don't and when applying this it _does_ work. If it bothers you, I'd recommend to refactor the stylings non-specific to a `<table>` element and apply them to your own class.